# Where is the "USER_HOME" folder for Gradle properties?

Tags: android, gradle

Basically , I'm doing a course in udacity and making the app they are teaching. The videos are pretty old and new information is given as text in the git directory. One of the changes I have to do is add a gradle.properties entry. However, I do not know where the folder they specified is located. 
I've been stuck trying to find it for quite a while. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is what they asked me to do.

[image]

My android SDK is located here

[image]

I do my projects in the desktop folder.

Comment: Try `B:\Users\ahmed`. Also `System.getProperty("user.home")` might give you the right directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`USER_HOME` usually refers to your home directory as determined by the operating system. In Windows, this is `C:\Users\<your user name>`.

Answer (score 1):

%USER_HOME% Means Directory of Which User Account in windows you are using for example: Your User Account Name in Windows is Syed Kamran So Your %USER_HOME% Will be C:/Users/Syed Kamran,
hope You Batter Understand Now,