# Gradle nexus password in a file in Android Studio - create Global Properties

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here's my code:

Build.Gradle (project):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-public/"
            credentials {
                username = nexusUsername
                password = nexusPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.properties (Project Properties):

```
nexusUrl=*********
nexusUsername=*********
nexusPassword=******
```

**I would like to have the nexusUrl, nexusUsername in an external text file in a global variable instead of a project variable**

but this error keeps showing:

```
Error:(24, 0) Could not get unknown property 'nexusUrl' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you thinking of passing the properties thru CLI?

Comment: Nope, I was trying to avoid having the password directly on Gradle because when I share with other programmers we don't want other people to see our password and username. That's why I was thinking in having an external file with the password and username instead of having it on Gradle.Properties

Comment: But your question states that you're specifying those properties in gradle.properties. If it's not in gradle.properties, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to solve it. In fact what I wanted was to have the gradle properties as a global variable instead of the project directory.

So I moved the usernames and passwords to 'USER_HOME/.gradle.'

USER_HOME usually refers to your home directory as determined by the operating system. In Windows, this is C:\Users\. As stated by Code-Apprentice in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175388/where-is-the-user-home-folder-for-gradle-propertie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175388/where-is-the-user-home-folder-for-gradle-properties)s

Tutorial on global variables are here:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2015/10/gradle-goodness-setting-global.html

Here's my solution code:

Build.Gradle (project):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-public/"
            credentials {
                username = nexusUsername
                password = nexusPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.properties (Global Properties):

```
nexusUrl=*********
nexusUsername=*********
nexusPassword=******
```

Thank you for your help guys (I've edited my question to reflect the problem)